# SQL Syntax Error - updating while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, syntax-error

Could anyone help me understand why I'm getting a syntax error when trying to run this query?

```
UPDATE exp_store_orders
SET exp_store_orders.order_status_name = "Digital"
    JOIN exp_store_order_items
        ON exp_store_orders.id = exp_store_order_items.order_id
    JOIN exp_channel_data
        ON exp_store_order_items.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id
GROUP BY exp_store_order_items.order_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE exp_channel_data.field_id_50 WHEN '' THEN null ELSE 1 END) =     COUNT(exp_store_order_items.order_id)
```

This brings up the ID's for the orders I'd like to update, but for some reason the above kicks back a syntax error.

```
SELECT exp_store_orders.id
FROM exp_store_orders
    JOIN exp_store_order_items
        ON exp_store_orders.id = exp_store_order_items.order_id
    JOIN exp_channel_data
        ON exp_store_order_items.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id
GROUP BY exp_store_order_items.order_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE exp_channel_data.field_id_50 WHEN '' THEN null ELSE 1 END) =     COUNT(exp_store_order_items.order_id)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN exp_store_order_items
        ON exp_store_orders.id = exp_store_order_items.ord' at line 3

Comment: Is there a field_id_49 ? Also, it's a little odd to *group by* the thing that you're counting !?!?! If it was me, I'd start over with some proper DDLs and a desired result.

Comment: Yes there's a field_id_49.

Comment: So here's what I'm trying to do. I need a way to mark orders on our store which are purely digital content. Digital items have a url in field_id_50, there can be multiple items per order, so I'm counting the number or items with a URL and comparing that number to the total number of items in the order.

Comment: Are you allowed to normalize the schema?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't set up this database and that's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax in MySQL for an `update` with `join` is to have the `join` *before* the `set`.  In addition, `group by` is not allowed in an `update`.

Instead, get the list from the subquery and use another `join` to set the rows.  The subquery doesn't actually need `exp_store_orders`, so that can be removed:

```
UPDATE exp_store_orders o JOIN
       (SELECT oi.order_id
        FROM exp_store_order_items oi JOIN
             exp_channel_data cd
             ON oi.entry_id = cd.entry_id
        GROUP BY oi.order_id
        HAVING COUNT(CASE cd.field_id_50 WHEN '' THEN null ELSE 1 END) = COUNT(oi.order_id)
       ) ou
       on o.id = ou.order_id
    SET o.order_status_name = 'Digital';
```

Comment: This seems like it's going to work, could you please explain what's going on with the 'ou' after the subquery? It's giving me this: #1054 - Unknown column 'ou.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: It's supposed to be seeing the subquery as another table that it's joining with correct? I wonder why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the WHERE clause in your statement.

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```